# How to vary the thickness of doughnut chart, using ChartJs.?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

How to vary the thickness of doughnut chart,  using [ChartJs](http://chartjs.org)

Comment: Try to play with percentageInnerCutout : 50 in Doughnut.defaults. It should vary the thickness.

Comment: You should accept the provider answer; it seems to answer your question :)

Answer (score 149, accepted):

since version 2 the field has been renamed to cutoutPercentage.

cutoutPercentage
Number  50 - for doughnut, 0 - for pie
The percentage of the chart that is cut out of the middle.

It can be used like this

```js
var options = {        
    cutoutPercentage: 40
};
```

more details here
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart-chart-options

Update: Since version 3

```js
var options = {        
    cutout: 40
};

var options = {        
    cutout: '40%'
};
```

According to the documentation at release notes of 3.x

> Doughnut `cutoutPercentage` was renamed to `cutout` and accepts pixels as numer and percent as string ending with `%`.

Comment: What if you had nested doughnuts?

Comment: then you would use `weight` (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html#styling)

Answer (score 44):

```
var options = {        
     cutoutPercentage: 70
};
```

Answer (score 24):

use, [percentageInnerCutout](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/), like:

```
var options = {        
    percentageInnerCutout: 40
};
myNewChart = new Chart(ct).Doughnut(data, options);
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nM7Sg/)

Comment: The answer by tetchen9 is better!

Comment: @tetchen9's answer below is the correct answer, currently I haven't seen any attribute mentioned in this answer `percentageInnerCutout`, its `cutoutPercentage` now. Refer http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html

Answer (score 8):

Since version 3 the field has been renamed to **cutout**.

It can be used like this since version 3 the field has been renamed to cutout.

50% - for doughnut, 0 - for pie

It can be used like this

[cutout description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3kIk.png)

```
var option = {
    cutout:40
}
```

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html

Answer (score 6):

If you are using chart.js for Angular via [ng2-charts](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/) you would do something like this in your component.html file:

```
// component.html file

<canvas baseChart [options]='chartOptions'>
</canvas>

// Do note that other required directives are missing in this example, but that I chose to highlight the 'options' directive
```

And do something like this in your component.ts file:

```
//component.ts file

chartOptions = {
  cutoutPercentage: 80
};
```

A helpful source of information: [available chart directives](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts) and [config options for the [options] directive](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html)

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to add how to achieve this exactly in React.

```
this.myChart = new Chart(this.chartRef.current, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  options: {
    cutout:120
  },
  data: {
    labels: this.props.data.map(d => d.label),
    datasets: [{
      data: this.props.data.map(d => d.value),
      backgroundColor:  Object.values(CHART_COLORS)
    }]
  }
});}
```

Answer (score 1):

In ng2-chart v3 with new types, in configraution option need to add chart type;

```
**ChartConfiguration<'doughnut'>['options']** 


doughnutChartOptions: ChartConfiguration<'doughnut'>['options'] = {
    cutout: '50%', // percentage of chart to cut out of the middle
    //cutout: 100, // pixels
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For vue-chartjs (tested with Nuxt), if setting options doesn't work, try :

> Chart.defaults.doughnut.cutoutPercentage = 80

Note that it will change all the doughnuts cutout.