# angular-chart.js doughnut chart : How do I change width of the arc of a doughnut?

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I am using angular-chart.js library(https://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/ ) for implementing doughnut chart.

How do I change width of the arc of a doughnut?

Comment: Have you checked chart.js options: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart-chart-options?

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014123/how-to-vary-the-thickness-of-doughnut-chart-using-chartjs).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to set the "cutoutPercentage" option in your chart-options. The default value for a doughnut chart is 50. Numbers closer to 100 will have more empty space in the middle, numbers closer to 0 will have less empty space in the middle of the doughnut.

In your controller:

```
$scope.options = {cutoutPercentage: 75};
$scope.data = [213, 546];
$scope.labels = ['Label 1', 'Label 2'];
```

In you html:

```
<canvas class="chart chart-doughnut" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-options="options"> </canvas>
```