# Inner Radius is not changed in Chart.js (Doughnut Chart)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic2, chart.js

I am using Chart.js I want a half doughnut chart just like the image below. But I am failed to change the thickness of the pie. I tried the property innerRadius but still it's not working

[image]

Here is my code

```
public getHalfDoughnutChart(records) {
    let data = {
       labels: ["Worked Hours","Remaining Hours"],
       datasets: [{
       label: 'Today\'s Worked Hours',
       data: [records.length? records[0].duration.hour: 0,9],
       backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(75, 174, 79, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'
       ]
     }]
 };

    let options = {
      circumference: Math.PI,
      rotation: 1.0 * Math.PI,
      innerRadius: "10%",
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      layout:{
        padding:40
      }, 
    }

     return this.getChart(this.halfDoughnutCanvas.nativeElement, "doughnut", data, options);
  }



getChart(context, chartType, data, options?) {
   return new Chart(context, {
      type: chartType,
      data: data,
      options: options
   });
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use `percentageInnerCutout` property in `options` object

```
let options = {
  circumference: Math.PI,
  rotation: 1.0 * Math.PI,
  percentageInnerCutout: 10,
  legend: {
    display: false
  },
  layout:{
    padding:40
  }, 
}
```

You can also check this question [How to vary the thickness of doughnut chart, using ChartJs.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014123/how-to-vary-the-thickness-of-doughnut-chart-using-chartjs)

**P.S.** As I understand it depends of version, so

If Chart.js version > **2.0** use `cutoutPercentage`

Otherwise use `percentageInnerCutout`

Comment: what chart.js version do you use?

Answer (score 2):

In chart JS 2.0 it should look like this

```
var options = {        
    cutoutPercentage: 40
};
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VVeOZZ?editors=0010