# Chart.js how to set cutoutPercentages for each dataset

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[image: chart]

In picture, I want Dataset2 be thicker than dataset1. How can custom doughnut chart like the picture?

Comment: Might be a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014123/how-to-vary-the-thickness-of-doughnut-chart-using-chartjs - Does this solve your problem?

Comment: EDIT: Haven't seen before, that you want a different `cutoutPercentages` value for each dataset. This isn't possible at the moment, but a feature request was created in September 2017 on github. There you can also find a creative workaround for the moment: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4724

Answer (score 4):

This feature was added in v2.8 in 2019 (https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/5951).

You can now use the `weight` property to assign relative widths of datasets.

```js
// following Timo Hulzenboom's example
datasets: [
  {
    data: [50, 30, 20],
    backgroundColor: ['#64D28C', '#F49356', '#F45656']
    weight: 0.33, // will be half as thick
  },
  {
    data: [memoryUsageValue, leftoverMemory],
    backgroundColor: [PercentageColor, '#FFFFFF']
    weight: 0.67,
  }
]
```

Edit: additional documentation at https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html#styling

Answer (score 0):

I was also searching for this option havent found it yet.
For now I added an extra dataset with borderWidth: 42 so that the sides of ether the inner data or outdoor

```
datasets: [
  {
    data: [100],
    backgroundColor: ['#FFFFFF'],
    borderWidth: 42
  },
  {
    data: [50, 30, 20],
    backgroundColor: ['#64D28C', '#F49356', '#F45656']
  },
  {
    data: [memoryUsageValue, leftoverMemory],
    backgroundColor: [PercentageColor, '#FFFFFF']
  }
]
```

[Colored borders to show how it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUG0k.png)

[Non colored border for result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDipL.png)

Answer (score -1):

There is a weight: prob you can add yo your datasets